# Erro ao conectar com o banco de dados firebird

Tags: java, firebird, conexão

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação web e quero utilizar java e html.
Bom depois de tudo configurado e pronto para um pequeno teste de conexao o seguinte erro ocorre:

```
Fev 09, 2016 1:28:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/TesteTemplateImport] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jsp.main_jsp._jspService(main_jsp.java:190)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Sou iniciante e nunca criei uma aplicação web, segue abaixo meu algoritmo para conexao com o banco:

```
package teste;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexao {

static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:firebirdsql:192.168.1.225/3050:D:/Dados/Suporte/Sisplan/Base/Belfast.GDB?sql_dialect=3";

static final String USER = "SYSDBA";
static final String PASS = "masterkey";

public static Connection getConexao() throws SQLException {

    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    return DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

   }


}
```

Tem um pequeno detalhe que acredito que devo mencionar, esse erro ocorre não no momento em que eu faço o start do servidor. Ele inicia a aplicação rodando no eclipse, vou até o navegador web digito o endereço do servidor, ele abre a pagina porem quando executo um select ai sim o log do erro aparece.

Este é meu código dentro da pagina html:

```
<%@ page import="teste.Conexao" %>
<%@ page import="teste.UsuarioDao" %>
<%@ page import="teste.Usuario" %>

<%  

UsuarioDao udao = new UsuarioDao();

Usuario usuario = (Usuario) udao.buscar("12345678");

out.print(usuario.getNome());
%>
```

Aqui esta meu select:

```
public Usuario buscar(String rg) {
    conectar();

    String sql = "SELECT nome FROM ENTIDADE_001 WHERE CODCLI = " + rg;

    try {
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String rG = rs.getString("rg");
            String nome = rs.getString("nome");

            pessoa = new Usuario(rG, nome);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        desconectar();
    }

    return pessoa;
}
```

E sim. Já adicionei o .jar correto com a mesma versão do meu jdk e minha variavel de ambiente HAVA_HOME nao tem espaços em branco e esta apontando corretamente para pasta da minha jdk.

Comment: Você faz `Conexao.getConexao();` na sua página, porém não faz uso (pelo menos com os códigos que postou) desse elemento. Outra dúvida que eu tenho é sobre a instanciação do elemento `pessoa`, que é retornado no método `buscar`. Caso nenhum usuário seja encontrado, qual o retorno para a página?

Comment: Verdade amigo, nem percebi. Mas esse codigo eu copiei de uma aba que estava usando para alteração e testes. Passou despercebido. Mas em fim o metodo getConexao() é chamado dentro do metodo conectar(). E o retorno para a pagina é apenas o nome do usuario impresso entre textos prontos aqui do template. Coisa simples apenas para testar a conexao.

Comment: Modifiquei o algoritmo para tirar qualquer duvida. Afinal pode ser uma coisa banal que esta ocasionando tanta dor de cabeça pra um dia.

Comment: Você já verificou se o "rg" que está sendo passado como parâmetro do método `buscar` está, de fato, com o valor que você está enviando?

Comment: Acabei de testar aqui amigo, passando o numero de um rg existente na minha tabela funcionou. Porem eu preciso buscar esse valor através de um form da minha pagina de login. Eu tentei request.getParameter("passoword"); dentro do escopo da tag <% %> . Porem é obvio que estou fazendo isso errado ja que funcionou agora com o rg setado diretamente no metodo buscar(). Algum post pra me ajudar sobre isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se [esse material](http://www.devmedia.com.br/javaserver-pages-autenticacao-de-login-com-jsp-e-postgresql/31849) lhe ajuda a encontrar o "caminho das pedras".

Neste exemplo é criado um esquema de autenticação bem elaborado. Você não precisa se prender aos pormenores que o autor trata, basta focar no que você está de fato precisando.

Creio que a análise das listagens 10 e 13 lhe serão de grande ajuda no entendimento da interação entre a página JSP e o back-end da aplicação.

Comment: Perfeito, acho que é exatamente isso que eu preciso. Muito obrigado.